# Is every set smaller than a regular cardinal, constructively?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, constructive-mathematics

Constructively, my only interest in regular cardinals is in terms of the “$\Sigma$-universes” they generate. By a *$\Sigma$-universe*, I mean a collection of triples $(X,Y,f: X \to Y)$ closed under base change, composition, and isomorphism – here $X,Y$ are sets and $f: X \to Y$ is a function between them. A $\Sigma$-universe can be viewed as a category where the morphisms are pullback squares. Let's say that a $\Sigma$-universe $U$ is *essentially small* or *representable* if, when viewed as a category in this way, it has a weakly terminal object.

In ZFC, representable $\Sigma$-universes are (almost) in bijection with regular cardinals. The bijection sends a regular cardinal $\kappa$ to the collection of functions with fibers of size $<\kappa$. The regularity of $\kappa$ corresponds to closure of the $\Sigma$-universe under composition.

Let's say

- *there are enough representable $\Sigma$-universes* if every function $f: X \to Y$ is contained in some representable $\Sigma$-universe.

In ZFC, there are enough representable $\Sigma$-universes because there are arbitrarily large regular cardinals.

**Question:**

1. Is it true constructively that there are enough representable $\Sigma$-universes? I assume this may depend on what one means by “constructively”, but I don't know what the appropriate dividing lines might be.
2. If not, are there natural conditions on a constructive set theory that ensure the existence of enough representable $\Sigma$-universes?
3. Is it true constructively that the poset of representable $\Sigma$-universes is directed? How about if I have a set-indexed family of representable $\Sigma$-universes – can I find another one containing them all?

Comment: You might want to look for REA, the regular extension axiom, which is usually used within constructive Zermelo-Fraenkel CZF. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+extension+axiom and the references there, in particular the paper by M. Rathjen and B. Lubarsky.

Comment: Gitik's model in which [every uncountable cardinal is singular](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02760939) seems like it might be relevant.

Comment: What is a "base change"?  Also, what is a function?  In set theory, it would be a set of ordered pairs, but you may speak a different language.

Comment: @Goldstern I don't intend anything exotic by "function" -- a function $f: X \to Y$ is the same thing as a subset $S \subseteq X \times Y$ such that $\forall x \in X \exists! y \in Y S(x,y)$. I'm sure there are subtleties about this that I don't have an appreciation of, so let me know if that's not sufficiently clear. Base change of $f: X \to Y$ along $g: Y' \to Y$ means the projection function $X \times_Y Y' \to Y'$. Here $X \times_Y Y' = \{(x,y) \in X \times Y' \mid f(x) = g(y)\}$. Here $g$ is an arbitrary function (not assumed to be in the $\Sigma$-universe).

Comment: The intention in formulating this in terms of maps $f: X \to Y$ was for such a map to constitute a family of sets $\{X_y\}_{y \in Y}$ indexed by $Y$. But I'm suddenly realizing that this might not be a correct formulation of this notion in some constructive settings. I'm not sure how to formulate my question in such settings.

Comment: Excellent question. Tim, in intuitionistic set theory, the correspondence between maps with codomain $Y$ and $Y$-indexed sets still works, so I think your formulation is just fine. I'm wondering: Is even the collection of triples $(X,Y,f)$ where $X$ and $Y$ admit surjections from $\mathbb{N}$ a $\Sigma$-universe, constructively? That seems to be the most basic example classically. But I don't immediately see that it works constructively, because I don't see why fibers should be countable again.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt In the formulation I had in mind, there would be no size restriction on $Y$ -- e.g. I'd expect "maps with finite fibers" to form a $\Sigma$-universe. The nlab article that godelian links to above in turn links to an ncafe discussion from 2012 where Benno van den Berg [gives a definition](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/04/pssl_93_trip_report.html#c041292) that seems similar in spirit. He worries about some kind of issue about theories with weak comprehension. Mike Shulman replies with an alternative definition...

Comment: Both of them use entire relations rather than functions -- maybe in a setting like a topos with some impredicativity one doesn't have to worry about this kind of thing? I should point out that this discussion also leads to [a note by van den Berg](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.vandenberg3/papers/WISC.pdf) where he shows (see the final remark) that in ZF, the axiom [WISC](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/WISC) implies there are arbitrarily large regular cardinals. (there's some discussion under the previous ncafe link too). I don't understand what's going on well enough to see if this generalizes.

Comment: But the question of whether there's a notion of "countable" which forms a $\Sigma$-universe seems like a good place to start. Maybe one has to work with subquotients of $\mathbb N$ rather than quotients. I'll also remark that the notion is reminiscent of the way object classifiers work in $\infty$-topoi.

Comment: It might be worth considering whether any predicative topos, in Benno's sense, has _internally_ 'enough regular sets', where by regular I mean one of the characterisations on the nLab page about regular cardinals in terms of small categories of sets having colimits up to a certain size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are enough representable $\Sigma$-universes in any regular locally cartesian closed category with disjoint coproducts and $W$-types. One can show the category of sets has $W$-types in $\mathbf{ZF}$ and even $\mathbf{IZF}$. So I don't think any form of choice or existence of regular ordinal is necessary for this particular statement, although there are related statements that do require the existence of regular sets (I believe some of the results in algebraic set theory are like this). It's not provable in $\mathbf{CZF}$ that $\mathbf{Set}$ has $W$-types but it follows from axioms that are often added such as $\bigcup-\mathbf{REA}$ and holds in the type theory interpretation of set theory as long as the type theory has enough inductive types (if I recall correctly this means each universe of small types is closed under $W$-types).

Given $f : A \to B$, for each $b \in B$ we write $A_b$ for the fibre over $b$. We then define $U$ to be $W$-type defined as the smallest set closed under the following operations.

1. $U$ contains an element $\ast$
2. If $b \in B$ and $g : A_b \to U$, then $U$ contains an element $\sup(b, g)$.

We then define a function $\operatorname{Br}$ from $U$ to sets by recursion as follows. It's a little tricky to formalise this in a predicatively acceptable way, but I think this can be done using the notion of paths like in Theorem 2.1.5 in Benno van den Berg's [thesis](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.vandenberg3/thesis/mythesis.pdf) (essentially branches are maximal paths).

1. $\operatorname{Br}(\ast) = 1$
2. If $b \in B$ and $g : A_b \to U$, then $\operatorname{Br}(\sup(b, g)) = \Sigma_{a \in A_b} \operatorname{Br}(g(a))$

We can think of $W$-type as sets of well founded trees, and in this case $\operatorname{Br}(u)$ is the set of branches of the tree $u$. We then take the universe to be the projection $\pi_0 : \Sigma_{u \in U} \operatorname{Br}(u) \to U$.

Note that we can define a map $t : B \to U$ as follows. Given $b \in B$, define $t(b)$ to be $\sup(b, \lambda x.\ast)$. Then for each $b$, $\operatorname{Br}(t(b))$ is isomorphic to $A_b$, and so $f$ is a pullback of $\pi_0$ along $t$.

Next we show that if $u \in U$ and $h : \operatorname{Br}(u) \to U$, then we can define $s(u, h) \in U$ such that $\operatorname{Br}(s(u, h)) \cong \Sigma_{x \in \operatorname{Br}(u)} \operatorname{Br}(h(x))$. We do this by recursion (and check it works by induction).

1. If $u = \ast$, then $\operatorname{Br}(u)$ has one element, say $0$. Take $s(u, h)$ to be $h(0)$.
2. If $u = \sup(b, g)$, then for each $a \in A_b$, $h : \Sigma_{a \in A_b} \operatorname{Br}(g(a)) \to U$ restricts to a morphism $h_a : \operatorname{Br}(g(a)) \to U$. Take $s(u, h)$ to be $\sup(b, \lambda a.s(g(a), h_a))$.

(The way to visualise this is that are given a function from branches of a tree to trees, and we glue each tree to the end of its corresponding branch to get a bigger tree.)

We can now use this to show that pullbacks of $\pi_0 : \Sigma_{u \in U} \operatorname{Br}(u) \to U$ are closed under composition. Every pullback is isomorphic to one where the codomain is an object $Y$, the bottom of the pullback is a map $t : Y \to U$ and the map is the projection $\Sigma_{y \in Y} \operatorname{Br}(t(y)) \to Y$. If we are given two composable maps $X \to Y$ and $Y \to Z$ that are both pullbacks of $\pi_0$, say along $t : Z \to U$ and $r : Y \to U$, then the maps are isomorphic to ones where $Y = \Sigma_{z \in Z} \operatorname{Br}(t(z))$ and $X = \Sigma_{z \in Z} \Sigma_{w \in \operatorname{Br}(t(z))} \operatorname{Br}(r(z, w))$. We can then use the map $s$ constructed above to witness the composition as a pullback of $\pi_0$. Namely, for each $z \in Z$, $r$ restricts to a map $r_z : \operatorname{Br}(t(z)) \to U$. We can then take $t' : Z \to U$ to be $t'(z) := s(t(z), r_z)$. The composition is then the pullback along $t'$.

I think the other two parts follow from the existence of enough representable $\Sigma$-universes. Because if we have a family of universes, we can take the coproduct of all the universes in the family and then construct a universe for that.

Comment: van den Berg's note showing how to do this in ZF was certainly suggestive that some W-type construction could work, but since he was interested in WISC in the note, it left the impression that something like WISC might also be necessary. So to see that it can be done with just W-types is fantastic. Thanks! It's also amazing to see that the statement as I formulated it is true in ZF even though there may not be enough regular cardinals in the ordinary sense! I suppose what must happen is that in the representation $B\to U$ constructed, not every smaller subset of $U$ appears as a fiber.

Comment: I was thinking of adding a "descent" condition saying that if $Y\times_X X' \to X'$ is in the universe for some surjection $X' \to X$, then $Y \to X$ is in the universe. I suppose in order to get enough representable $\Sigma$-universes satisfying this condition, perhaps something like WISC might be necessary.

Comment: That would definitely prevent the construction I gave from working. You can see e.g. Van den Berg, Moerdijk, Aspects of Predicative Algebraic Set Theory I, for a typical approach to this kind of thing and they include that descent condition in Proposition 2.10. They also use a weaker notion of representability that I think avoids some of these issues.